# Swift remove ONLY trailing spaces from string

Tags: string, swift3, nscharacterset

many examples in SO are fixing both sides, the leading and trailing. My request is only about the trailing. 
My input text is: "   keep my left side  "
Desired output: "   keep my left side"

Of course this command will remove both ends:

```
let cleansed = messageText.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
```

Which won't work for me.

How can I do it?

Comment: How about `rangeOfCharacter(from: .whitespaceAndNewlines.inverted)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A quite simple solution is regular expression, the pattern is *one or more(`+`) whitespace characters(`\s`) at the end of the string(`$`)*

```
let string = " keep my left side "
let cleansed = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s+$", 
                                         with: "", 
                                      options: .regularExpression)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the rangeOfCharacter function on string with a characterSet. This extension then uses recursion of there are multiple spaces to trim. This will be efficient if you only usually have a small number of spaces.

```
extension String {
    func trailingTrim(_ characterSet : CharacterSet) -> String {
        if let range = rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSet, options: [.anchored, .backwards]) {
            return self.substring(to: range.lowerBound).trailingTrim(characterSet)
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

---

`"1234   ".trailingTrim(.whitespaces)`

returns

`"1234"`

Answer (score 1):

Building on vadian's answer I found for Swift 3 at the time of writing that I had to include a range parameter. So:

```
func trailingTrim(with string : String) -> String {

    let start = string.startIndex
    let end = string.endIndex
    let range: Range<String.Index> = Range<String.Index>(start: start, end: end)


    let cleansed:String = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\s+$",
                                                                      withString: "",
                                                                      options: .RegularExpressionSearch,
                                                                      range: range)

    return cleansed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple. No regular expressions needed.

```
extension String {

    func trimRight() -> String {
        let c = reversed().drop(while: { $0.isWhitespace }).reversed()
        return String(c)
    }
}
```